# "Congress" vs "the Congress": Is the definite article needed before "Congress"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Both "the Congress" and "Congress" appear in Google searches. Which one of the sentences below is correct/ more common? Why?

> The president really had poor relations with Congress.

or

> The president really had poor relations with the Congress.

Answer (score 1):

"The president really had poor relations with Congress."

Would be more common.  Stating just "Congress" is generally understood to to mean the current one.  Using "the Congress" would be more appropriate when referring to a specific one.  i.e. "The 1886 Congress"